# C99 struct member initialization, containing UNION

Tags: struct, initialization, c99, member

I'd like to declare the array of below structure,

```
typedef struct {
    std::string key;
    union {
       bool b;
       int  i;
       double d;
       std::string s;
    } val;
} ttt;
```

and initialize the arrat with C99 type, designated way.

```
ttt a[] = {
   {
      .key = std::string("key a"),
      .val .. ???
```

How..?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this C or C++?  `std::string` is usually C++.

Comment: @JonathonS. Ah.. my mistake! :)